# Can xtext propose styled string in template proposals?

Tags: xtext

Can xtext propose styled string in template proposals? 
Normal `createCompletionProposal` could have that but I didn't find any API returning `StryledString` in `ITemplateProposalProvider` hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to extend TemplateProposal and add ICompletionProposalExtension6 in order to deal with styled strings in the display string of the template. That's not a class from Xtext but from the underlying Eclipse content proposal framework.